# How to check status of parity flag in 8086 microprocessor?

Tags: x86-16, microprocessors

Take for example the result of multiplication of two 16 bit numbers. How will the parity flag be affected in the 8086 microprocessor and on what basis?Do we consider the entire 32 bit result or just the lower 8 bits?

Answer (score 1):

If it's set according to the result, it's from the low 8 bits.  e.g. `add ax, bx` sets PF according to AL.

Not all instructions do that, though.  Consult the manual.  For example `mul` https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mul leaves PF undefined.

---

BTW, your question title doesn't match your question at all.  To *check* PF, you'd use an instruction like `jp` or `jnp`

Or `lahf` / `and ah, 1<<2` to store FLAGS into AH and then AND to isolate the PF bit.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAGS_register

Or on later CPUs, `setp al` or `cmovp eax, edx` would also be options.